# Is their a way out to launch an ios app on system boot without using voip key?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a ios app that constantly communicate with server over the internet. I need the app to start automatically when the device restarts and it should constantly run in background listening from server.

I have searched about this and found that only those [apps can start automatically which uses voice over ip](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) and the other solution is to use [Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202612).

But neither my app uses voice over ip nor I want the user to limit to use only one app(only my app) as in the case of guided access.

Is there any alternative way by which we can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: There probably isn't any alternative and for a good reason: apps that need to run constantly in the background drain the battery for no good reason and are usually a sign of bad design. If your app needs to react to something happening server side, look into push notifications.

Comment: @deadbeef My main concern is to start app on system boot automatically, for the app to run in background always I will use push notifications only as suggested by you and many others. So, I am looking for a way around to start my app automatically on device restart.