# IOS app needs to be running in background and should launch automatically on device reboot.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on a network security based Ios application. In which I need to continuously send UDP keepalive message to a device (LINUX based server) and fetch action when it is available at that device. Based on the action fetched from server we perform some operations in our app. This UDP keepalive needs to be sent to server irrespective of the app state i.e. foreground, background, suspended or terminated. Now the problems that I am facing are as follow:

Problem 1:
The problem is Apple does not allow the apps to continuously run in background without a using one of the following background modes in app settings: Audio and AirPlay, Location updates, Voice over IP, Newsstand downloads, External accessory communication, Uses Bluetooth LE accessories, Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory, Background fetch, Remote notifications.

As per the requirements of my app I think I can go with [Background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) or with external accessory communication. Now, the question is can we use background fetch to send UDP keealive and fetch action (not data as written in Background fetch doucmentation) from server and does this background fetch works even if app is terminated?

Problem 2:
In case user restarts the device I want the app to start automatically in background to send UDP keepalive without user intervention. I do not want to use push notification as it requires user interaction to launch application.

Can you please suggest any proper way by which I can solve the above two problems such that my app didn’t get rejected at apple store

Comment: afaik, you can't do this, & for a reason. On iOS devices, you're not allowed to "hijack" the device, as it wouldn't take that many apps doing this to cause performance issues, etc. I believe it's getting harder to do with newer versions of Android too, tho I don't know much about that. Ultimately, you have to leave it to the user to decide if they want the app to respond via something like a push notification.

Comment: As I have said before when you asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778015/) yesterday : **You can't have the OS start your app automatically when the device boots**. Period. You should thank Apple every day when you wake up for that. The best you could do is send push notifications to your app at regular intervals to wake it up and do some short action before it is paused again.

Comment: But what you should really do is try to come up with a better design for you system, one that doesn't require your app to run continuously in the background.